# Bootstrap - different text alignment at different breakpoints without media queries

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Bootstrap 3.3.6. I've come across a situation whereby I need to align text right on desktop, but centre on mobile.

Assume the following markup (also in [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/s36wLv33/1/)):

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150x150">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 text-right">
      <p>text here</p>
      <p>another line of text</p>
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

My question relates to having `.text-right` in the markup. This is one of many classes Bootstrap provides for alignment.

I could remove this, and then use media queries to target `.col-md-9` and change the text alignment by providing **separate** rules for `-md` and `-sm/-xs` devices. However, doing this means I'm effectively having to rewrite CSS that Bootstrap already includes (for example aligning text right with `.text-right`, or center `.text-center`).

I can also think of more complex examples of pre-written classes that Bootstrap provides.

Given that the use of these classes may differ on large/desktop devices, and small/mobile devices, is it correct to just use a media query and then rewrite all of the same CSS Bootstrap gives you for those styles? Or is there a better way?

I understand how it's possible to chain things like `col-md-9 col-sm-12 col-xs-12` to get different grid layouts on different devices. But is there some equivalent thing which allows you to apply other Bootstrap classes at these different breakpoints... or is it just a case of you have to use media queries and then supply the CSS every time?

In simplistic terms what I'm trying to do is say:

- `.col-md-9` == use `.text-right`
- `.col-sm-12` (or `.col-xs-12`) == use `.text-center`

My issue with writing media queries that target these things separately is that I'm having to write things such as `text-align: right` and `text-align: center` even though Bootstrap already provides the classes that do this. These are simple examples, and obviously where more complex CSS rules are required this becomes a burden.

Comment: I think you're... exaggerating the complexity & work involved in simply using a media query here... What's the issue with doing that? It's like 3 lines worth of code and you're done. The queries are also pre-written out for you on Bootstraps docs so you can literally copy and paste so that all you have to do is put your one text-align CSS rule in the brackets?

Comment: Potentially I am exaggerating the complexity - that's part of the question. Aligning text isn't a complex example because you could supply the media query (2 lines) plus `text-align: ` (3rd line). But there are other more complex utility classes Bootstrap provides which are more than just 1 line of CSS. Also, what if you wanted to use more than 1 of them for a specific `<div>`? If you think about just one rule, in one area, then yes it's no big deal. But across and entire site it can really bloat your CSS to keep rewriting stuff that's already in your `bootstrap.css` file, surely?

Comment: In order to do what you want with dynamic rules based on the class **without** some type of media query, in CSS isn't really possible...  You can do it with JS though but then it begs the question as to whether that is 'too much' for you

Comment: Please write media query for this.

Comment: Ok. All of these are interesting comments. I was just interested in whether media queries are the "right" way to go, or if I'm missing some trick to make this easier or the CSS smaller. I have no issue at all with writing media queries if they are needed, so this is the approach I will use.

Comment: @Andy What about if you wanted to use more than 1 of them for specific div? I mean.. you can create one class and apply it anywhere, on any div?

Comment: Sure. I've possibly been "over thinking" this to the point things became a bit obscure. Thank you for the insights.

Comment: @Andy I can see the appeal, but stuff like that is a bit specific I think for bootstrap to include by default. I guess you're wanting a universal `visible-*-*` type class to apply your own rules. Why not create them manually and then you have them forever for re-use :-)  P.S. I would also recommend you go to Bootstrap 3.3.7 unless you really need 3.3.6